# How to return the response to front end while processing csv file from S3 using Lamda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-serverless

New to AWS Lambda, Cognito, AWS API-Gateway and server-less computing.

My user uploads a csv file, and i want to insert it into Amazon RDS, and return a success or failure response to the user.

I understand that I can upload the file to S3(used cognito identity pools) and then write a lambda that trigger on upload to S3, which then insert the data from csv to Amazon RDS. I want to show the success or failure response from lambda to the user.

One way i thought about is:

- After upload to S3, show a message, "Upload successful. File processing"
- Then redirect user to a file list page, show the status of file there.
- Meanwhile, my lambda function will insert the file name into file table with status column as "IN PROGRESS", and update it's status depending upon the success/failure of csv insert.
- I will keep checking the status of file table every 10 seconds or so, and change the status in the file list page for the recent file, when the status is changed in file table.

Is there a better way to do this using aws server-less computing?

Answer (score 1):

Going with the serverless approach is good. If you're trying to perform real time notifications you can take a look at using [API Gateway with Web Socket APIs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-websocket-api.html).

You would enhance your suggestion by replacing the 10 second poll by opening a web socket connection instead.

Once the file is processed your Lambda would notify the web socket connection and then you would notify the customer.

This is how real time notification systems and instant messenger style applications tend to work.

Comment: in websocket, there is a connection id right? How to i connect it to S3? I mean how does the websocket know which customer to notify after file is processed?

Comment: Your Lambda after it has finished processing would would send a message to the connection id of your user. It basically is taking out the polling (check every 10 seconds) and replacing with web sockets. When you upload you could add the connection id as metadata or store the connection id in a dynamodb table against the file name.